# Why enclose a \verb block with curly braces?

Tags: verbatim, brackets, braces

Why would you enclose a \verb block with curly braces? Does it change anything? Consider the following examples:

```
The \verb|acmart| document is \verb|orange| and \verb|blue|. 

Use the {\verb|verb|} command to insert in-line code. 
You can also use {\verb|other commands like textt|}.
```

Comment: In the code you posted, the extra pairs of curly braces do nothing except create code clutter. As to *why* anybody would add the curly braces, I have no sensible explanation. OCD, maybe?

Comment: I never used the curly braces to enclose only a  `\verb` command and I'm still alive!  Even sometimes, I do not use `|` , but something else , and still work !  So `\relax`  `;-)`. What might not work is when the curly braces  are the argument of a command (e.g.:  `\emph{\verb+plus+}`   is a "fatal error" (means no PDF), while  `{\em\verb+plus+}`  is syntactically correct, although stupid, because you cannot emphasize the verbatim text).

Comment: Vote to reopen. The question is perhaps naive but enough clear  IMHO and I am willing to answer because could be useful for novices.

Comment: If this is a poll, then my answer is “there is no reason whatsoever for preferring `{\verb|xyz|}` to `\verb|xyz|`”.

Comment: All of your proposals in the answer suggests adding something in addition to the braces or how it is posted in the question. So, this question is still unclear to me.

Comment: Some of you seem to be wondering where on earth I found a `\verb` block enclosed by curly braces. I found it in a professional document put out by the association of computing machinery (ACM). They have a template named `sample-sigconf.tex` Inside the demo/sample they sometimes they put `\verb` statements inside of curly braces and sometimes they do not. I was just wondering if `\verb` inside curly braces or outside of curly braces was better practice, and why.

Comment: the examples you post are very weird, not only are the braces doing nothing, there is no reason at all to use `\verb` on text such as `orange`  it should just be `\texttt{orange}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It was an example. The fact that the string was "orange" is irrelevant. The question is why write something like `{\verb|xyz|}` instead of `\verb|xyz|` where `xyz` is **ANY** string whether that string be "orange" or something completely different from "orange."

Comment: @IdleCustard it was still a bad example, as many new users for some reason find `\verb` before `\texttt` and for text strings like you show `\texttt` is far more natural, so however the question is phrased the usual answer is "use texttt not verb".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why would you enclose a \verb block with curly braces?

To limit the scope of some other command also between the curly braces and before of `\verb`:

```
Lore {\color{red}\verb|ipsum|} dolor sit amet.
```

[image: mwe]

But note that the `{...}` group cannot be the argument of a command. The next code (supposedly equivalent) produces a fatal error:

```
Lore \textcolor{red}{\verb|ipsum|} dolor sit amet.
```

**`LaTeX Error: \verb illegal in command argument.`**

> Does it change anything?

Nothing if the group contain only the `\verb` command. It can change a lot if there another commands in the group, as showed above, and even if there are some space before and/or after each brace.

One of the first things that LaTeX users learn is that extra spaces between words are ignored. But maybe take more time note that this is not true when  there are curly braces among the spaces:

```
x                   x  % ---> produces "x x"

x{ { { { { } } } } }x  % --->  produces "x                   x"
```

And you must take into account that many macros without arguments can eat the next space-s, but obviously not not in they are after the left brace. Confusing at first, because many commands do not do that. This is a source for stupid mistakes even if you know well what you can expect in each case.

Therefore, if there are not a objective reason to embrace the verbatim text (as modify only it with another command) is safer and less prone to error is avoid them. In case of  space eaters macros, a space after the left brace may seem a good idea, but is better empty group  after the macro followed by one space (i.e.: `{}`) but left free the verbatim text. As matter of taste, you can replace `{}` by  simply `\` (or another spacer as `~`, or `\,`,  etc. if needed).

In summary, better an example that so much verbiage:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

Lore   \verb|ipsum| \par % OK (simpler, better?)  
Lore  {\verb|ipsum|}\par % OK
Lore{  \verb|ipsum|}\par % OK 
Lore { \verb|ipsum|}\par % Wrong! (space x2)

% but ...

\LaTeX     \verb|ipsum| \par % Wrong! (no space)  
\LaTeX    {\verb|ipsum|}\par % Wrong! (no space)
\LaTeX{    \verb|ipsum|}\par % OK
\LaTeX   { \verb|ipsum|}\par % OK
\LaTeX{}   \verb|ipsum| \par % OK
\LaTeX\    \verb|ipsum| \par % OK (simpler, better?)

% but ...

Lore {\Large     \verb|ipsum|}\par  % OK (simpler, better?)    
Lore {\Large    {\verb|ipsum|}}\par % OK
Lore {\Large{    \verb|ipsum|}}\par % Wrong  (space x2)
Lore {\Large {   \verb|ipsum|}}\par % Wrong  (space x2) 

\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks like you might enclose `\verb` in braces to make it easier to add additional modifiers at some later date, such as `\color{red}` For now, all we want to do is apply `\verb` to the word `ipsum` Maybe later we will apply several different modifiers to `ipsum` instead of just one.

Comment: @IdleCustard Probably what you will intend could be done, better and easier, with the help of some package.  To we aware of alternatives as `minted`,  visit  https://ctan.org/topic/verbatim and https://ctan.org/topic/listing for an  overview. In case of specific languages as R you can do even "literate programing" (not listed in these topics) because is done with a R package (`knitr`) that can highlighted automatically the R code (and even run it).